# running 100 files using a single command with subprocess

Tags: python

i want to run this command for around 100 files(subset_1 to subset_100) for motif analysis and store its respective output. I am trying to use subprocess initially to do this by creating a list. Suggest me how to run for 100 files.

command:

```
meme subset_*.fas -text -dna -mod anr -nmotifs 10 -w 8 -revcomp -maxsites 100 -bfile seqs.MEMEbkgr > subset_*.MEME
```

Here is a python script i am trying:

```
import subprocess
m = ['meme', 'subset_%s.fas', '-text', '-dna', '-mod', 'anr', '-nmotifs', 
     '1', '-w', '8', '-revcomp' '-maxsites' '100' '-bfile' 'seqs.MEMEbkgr' 
      '>' 'subset_%s.MEME'] 
for i in range(2): 
   finder_out = open("subset_%s", "w") 
   finder_out.close() 
   subprocess.call('m')
```

Comment: do you want all 100 files to append to that subset_.MEME file?

Comment: no. I need each subset in a separate file

Comment: Here is a python script i am trying. import subprocess
m =  ['meme', 'subset_%s.fas', '-text', '-dna', '-mod', 'anr', '-nmotifs', '1', '-w', '8', '-revcomp' '-maxsites' '100' '-bfile' 'seqs.MEMEbkgr' '>' 'subset_%s.MEME']

for i in range(2):
    finder_out = open("subset_%s", "w")
    finder_out.close()
    subprocess.call('m')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#as example to be short enough
command = "meme subset_{filenum}.fas > subset_{filenum}.MEME"

for i in range(100):
    param={"filenum":i} #this is used to replace {filenum} with i in comnmand
                        #param is dict with string as key
    command_t=command.format(**param)
    print command_t
    subprocess.call(command_t,shell=True)
```